# Как удалить неиспользуемую (паразитную) метку?

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано

https://rus.stackexchange.com/tags/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0./info

Возникла как дубликат аналогичной, но без точки в конце. Все вопросы я переметил, а сама метка осталась - кто-нибудь наверняка попадется...

По пунктам.
1. Обнаружил метку "грамматика." - она была у нескольких вопросов (три или четыре). Как возникла - не знаю, но при наличии метки "грамматика" - явно лишняя.
2. Все вопросы с этой меткой переметил: удалил неправильную, присвоил новую, без точки.
3. Убедился, что метка "грамматика." не исчезла за какое-то разумное время. 
И ей можно метить.

Вот, пожалуй, всё. 
Не думал, что из-за трех вопросов надо задействовать какую-то автоматическую процедуру.
Но сейчас вопрос решен. Только на будущее. 
Сейчас метку удалили.

Comment: Для ссылок на метки используйте синтаксис `[tag:грамматика.]` — [tag:грамматика.]

Comment: Да речь не о ссылках шла.

Comment: я понял, что речь шла о самих метках. Просто ссылка в начале вопроса непонятна в текущем виде. Исправить сам не могу, нет прав, поэтому предлагаю вам удобный синтаксис для ссылки на метку.

Comment: А, понял... Вот так [tag:грамматика]. Что дальше?

Comment: вместо ссылки используйте этот фрагмент. На несуществующие метки тоже можно давать такие ссылки. Для меток меты:  `[meta-tag:support]`

Comment: Так нету уже той метки.)))

Comment: Кстати, перевел статью с англоязычной меты про ошибку, которая распространена в технических вопросах. Вы же опытный участник, взгляните — встречается ли такое в вопросах на этом сайте? http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181472

Comment: что-то я забыл, вы же уже разобрались вчера с синтаксисом. ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменять метки вручную не обязательно, все делается автоматически. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [раздел создания синонимов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: так сказал же, что автоматически не удалилась...

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите проделанные вами шаги в вашем вопросе. Попробуем разобраться.

Comment: Сейчас все стало нормально. Возможно, просто не дождался. Что делал - дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky сайту Русский язык явно не хватает модератора. Всё чаще попадаются матерные и бессмысленные ответы и вопросы, с которыми пользователи ничего не могут сделать. В принципе, если не хватает людей могу помочь с модерацией, на ресурс захожу почти каждый день, хоть последнее время отвечаю редко.

Comment: @МаркИз А давайте соберемся и назначим!

Comment: @МаркИз Посмотрел. Действительно, много неоднозначных сообщений. Давайте попробуем собрать все проблемы и обсудить их в чате http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33997/.

Answer (score 2):

Это пример использования метки. Кстати, по нему можно заметить, что «грамматика.» уже синонимизирована к «грамматика» - ссылка ведет на вторую.

---

[грамматика](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Возникла как дубликат аналогичной, но без точки в конце. Все вопросы я переметил, а сама метка осталась - кто-нибудь наверняка попадется...

...